# jquery multiselect (call any function on selection time)

Tags: jquery, multi-select

Please tell me how to call any function at the time of any selection from multiselect.

eg. I have following items in multiselect,

```
abc
xyz
asdf
```

Suppose I click on abc to select and at this time how to call any function to work?

Comment: Please be more clear what you want. What is a b c suposed to be?

Comment: @Frederiek Probably `<select multiple><option>abc</option> ...`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `select` and having the property `multiple` as true you can write code in `.change()` event

```
$("#select1").change(function(){
    var currentValue = this.value;
});
```

[***Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsadasivan/AKjXw/)